# Make link in UILabel.attributedText *not* blue and *not* underlined

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsattributedstring

I want some words within my OHAttributedLabel to be links, but I want them to be colors other than blue and I don't want the underline.

This is giving me a blue link with underlined text:

```
 -(void)createLinkFromWord:(NSString*)word withColor:(UIColor*)color atRange:(NSRange)range{

    NSMutableAttributedString* mutableAttributedText = [self.label.attributedText mutableCopy];   

    [mutableAttributedText beginEditing];
    [mutableAttributedText addAttribute:kOHLinkAttributeName
                   value:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.somewhere.net"]
                   range:range];

    [mutableAttributedText addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
                   value:color
                   range:range];

    [mutableAttributedText addAttribute:(id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                   value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleNone]
                   range:range];
    [mutableAttributedText endEditing];


    self.label.attributedText = mutableAttributedText;

}
```

Since I'm using OHAttributedLabel, I also tried using the methods in it's `NSAttributedString+Attributes.h` category, but those return blue underlined links as well:

```
-(void)createLinkFromWord:(NSString*)word withColor:(UIColor*)color atRange:(NSRange)range{

NSMutableAttributedString* mutableAttributedText = [self.label.attributedText mutableCopy];

[mutableAttributedText setLink:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.somewhere.net"] range:range];
[mutableAttributedText setTextColor:color range:range];
[mutableAttributedText setTextUnderlineStyle:kCTUnderlineStyleNone range:range];

self.label.attributedText = mutableAttributedText;
}
```

If I comment out the line setting the links in each version, the text gets colored to what I pass in - that works. It just seems like setting the link is overriding this and turning it back to blue.

Unfortunately the apple docs page I found shows how to set the link text to blue and underline it, exactly what I don't need:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/ChangingAttrStrings.html

Answer (score 62, accepted):

So I ended up using TTTAttributedLabel:

```
-(void)createLinkFromWord:(NSString*)word withColor:(UIColor*)color atRange:(NSRange)range{
    NSMutableAttributedString* newTextWithLinks = [self.label.attributedText mutableCopy];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.reddit.com"];
    self.label.linkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, 
                                   NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)};
    [self.label addLinkToURL:url withRange:range];
}
```

I found that `OHAttributedLabel` actually does have methods to set links and declare colors and underline styles for those links. However, I wanted the links to be different colors based on a parameter. `TTTAttributedLabel` allows this by letting you set it's `linkAttributes` property for each link you create.

Comment: Also make sure to set `linkAttributes` before adding a link to the label.

Comment: Is there no other way to set the link color except with some github project? the linkAttributes property is not available for a UILabel.

Comment: I cant see where you use the "word" argument and the newTextWithLinks variable.

Answer (score 23):

I am using [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel).  I wanted to change the color of the linked text, and keep it underlined.  Pim's answer looked great, but didn't work for me. Here's what did work:

```
label.linkAttributes = @{ (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor magentaColor],
                           (id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName : [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] };
```

Note: if you don't want the text underlined, then remove the kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName key from the dictionary.

Comment: Great! This works for me too. But other answers don't.

Comment: Yes, only this answer works! Using NSForegroundColorAttributeName make no sense. You must use kCTForegroundColorAttributeName. Refer to [this issue](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/issues/455)

Answer (score 22):

Here's is my improved version of Ramsel's already great answer.
I believe it's much more readable, and I hope it will come to good use.

```
label.linkAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                          NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] };
```

Here's [a list of other attibute names](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html).

Comment: UILabel does not have a linkAttributes property

Comment: Correct @Softlion, but TTTAttributedLabel does. Or at least it did 4 years ago. I have no idea whether this answer is still good.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using a **`UITextView`**, you might have to change the `tintColor` property to change the link color.

Answer (score 5):

If you're like me and really don't want to use TTT (or need it in your own custom implementation where you're drawing in other weird ways):

First, subclass NSLayoutManager and then override as follows:

```
- (void)showCGGlyphs:(const CGGlyph *)glyphs 
           positions:(const CGPoint *)positions 
               count:(NSUInteger)glyphCount
                font:(UIFont *)font 
              matrix:(CGAffineTransform)textMatrix 
          attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
           inContext:(CGContextRef)graphicsContext
{
   UIColor *foregroundColor = attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

   if (foregroundColor)
   {
      CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(graphicsContext, foregroundColor.CGColor);
   }

   [super showCGGlyphs:glyphs 
             positions:positions 
                 count:glyphCount 
                  font:font 
                matrix:textMatrix 
            attributes:attributes 
             inContext:graphicsContext];
}
```

This is more or less telling the layout manager to actually respect `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` from your attributed string **always** instead of the weirdness Apple has internally for links.

If all you need to do is get a layout manager which draws correctly (as I needed), you can stop here. If you need an actually UILabel, it's painful but possible.

First, again, subclass UILabel and slap in all of these methods.

```
- (NSTextStorage *)textStorage
{
   if (!_textStorage)
   {
      _textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] init];
      [_textStorage addLayoutManager:self.layoutManager];
      [self.layoutManager setTextStorage:_textStorage];
   }

   return _textStorage;
}

- (NSTextContainer *)textContainer
{
   if (!_textContainer)
   {
      _textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] init];
      _textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
      _textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = self.numberOfLines;
      _textContainer.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode;
      _textContainer.widthTracksTextView = YES;
      _textContainer.size = self.frame.size;

      [_textContainer setLayoutManager:self.layoutManager];
   }

   return _textContainer;
}

- (NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager
{
   if (!_layoutManager)
   {
      // Create a layout manager for rendering
      _layoutManager = [[PRYLayoutManager alloc] init];
      _layoutManager.delegate = self;
      [_layoutManager addTextContainer:self.textContainer];
   }

   return _layoutManager;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];

   // Update our container size when the view frame changes
   self.textContainer.size = self.bounds.size;
}

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   [super setFrame:frame];

   CGSize size = frame.size;
   size.width = MIN(size.width, self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth);
   size.height = 0;
   self.textContainer.size = size;
}

- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
   [super setBounds:bounds];

   CGSize size = bounds.size;
   size.width = MIN(size.width, self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth);
   size.height = 0;
   self.textContainer.size = size;
}

- (void)setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:(CGFloat)preferredMaxLayoutWidth
{
   [super setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:preferredMaxLayoutWidth];

   CGSize size = self.bounds.size;
   size.width = MIN(size.width, self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth);
   self.textContainer.size = size;
}
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines
{
  // Use our text container to calculate the bounds required. First save our
  // current text container setup
  CGSize savedTextContainerSize = self.textContainer.size;
  NSInteger savedTextContainerNumberOfLines = self.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines;

  // Apply the new potential bounds and number of lines
  self.textContainer.size = bounds.size;
  self.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines;

  // Measure the text with the new state
  CGRect textBounds;
  @try
  {
      NSRange glyphRange = [self.layoutManager 
                            glyphRangeForTextContainer:self.textContainer];
      textBounds = [self.layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:glyphRange
                                       inTextContainer:self.textContainer];

      // Position the bounds and round up the size for good measure
      textBounds.origin = bounds.origin;
      textBounds.size.width = ceilf(textBounds.size.width);
      textBounds.size.height = ceilf(textBounds.size.height);
  }
  @finally
  {
      // Restore the old container state before we exit under any circumstances
      self.textContainer.size = savedTextContainerSize;
      self.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = savedTextContainerNumberOfLines;
   }

   return textBounds;
}

- (void)setAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)attributedText
{
    // Pass the text to the super class first
    [super setAttributedText:attributedText];

    [self.textStorage setAttributedString:attributedText];
}
- (CGPoint)_textOffsetForGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphRange
{
   CGPoint textOffset = CGPointZero;

   CGRect textBounds = [self.layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:glyphRange 
                                                     inTextContainer:self.textContainer];
   CGFloat paddingHeight = (self.bounds.size.height - textBounds.size.height) / 2.0f;
   if (paddingHeight &gt; 0)
   {
       textOffset.y = paddingHeight;
   }

   return textOffset;
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   // Calculate the offset of the text in the view
   CGPoint textOffset;
   NSRange glyphRange = [self.layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:self.textContainer];
   textOffset = [self _textOffsetForGlyphRange:glyphRange];

   // Drawing code
   [self.layoutManager drawBackgroundForGlyphRange:glyphRange atPoint:textOffset];

   // for debugging the following 2 line should produce the same results
   [self.layoutManager drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:glyphRange atPoint:textOffset];
   //[super drawTextInRect:rect];
}
```

[Shamelessly taken from here](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2015/03/customizing-uilabel-hyperlinks/). Incredibly work on the original author's part for working this all out.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 2.3 example for `TTTAttributedLabel`:

```swift
yourLabel.linkAttributes       = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor(),
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSNumber(bool: true)
]
yourLabel.activeLinkAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8),
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSNumber(bool: false)
]
```

Swift 4

```swift
yourLabel.linkAttributes = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.grayColor(),
    .underlineStyle: NSNumber(value: true)
]
yourLabel.activeLinkAttributes = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.grayColor().withAlphaComponent(0.7),
    .underlineStyle: NSNumber(value: false)
]
```

Comment: UILabel does not have linkAttributes

Comment: @AliAlaoi this example for TTTAttributedLabel

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3 following way worked out for me using `TTTAttributedLabel`:

1) Add a label on the storyboard and define its class to be `TTTAttributedLabel`
[image: Storyboard view]

2) In code define 
`@IBOutlet var termsLabel: TTTAttributedLabel!`

3) Then in `ViewDidLoad` write these lines

```
termsLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "By using this app you agree to the Privacy Policy & Terms & Conditions.")
guard let labelString = termsLabel.attributedText else {
            return
        }
        guard let privacyRange = labelString.string.range(of: "Privacy Policy") else {
            return
        }
        guard let termsConditionRange = labelString.string.range(of: "Terms & Conditions") else {
            return
        }

        let privacyNSRange: NSRange = labelString.string.nsRange(from: privacyRange)
        let termsNSRange: NSRange = labelString.string.nsRange(from: termsConditionRange)

        termsLabel.addLink(to: URL(string: "privacy"), with: privacyNSRange)
        termsLabel.addLink(to: URL(string: "terms"), with: termsNSRange)

        termsLabel.delegate = self
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: termsLabel.attributedText!)
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 12)!], range: termsNSRange)
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 12)!], range: privacyNSRange)
        attributedText.addAttributes([kCTForegroundColorAttributeName as String: UIColor.orange], range: termsNSRange)
        attributedText.addAttributes([kCTForegroundColorAttributeName as String: UIColor.green], range: privacyNSRange)
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue], range: termsNSRange)
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue], range: privacyNSRange)
        termsLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

It would look like this
[image: Simulator View]

4) Finally write the delegate function of `TTTAttributedLabel` so that you can open links on tap

```
public func attributedLabel(_ label: TTTAttributedLabel!, didSelectLinkWith url: URL!) {
    switch url.absoluteString  {
    case "privacy":
        SafariBrowser.open("http://google.com", presentingViewController: self)
    case "terms":
        SafariBrowser.open("http://google.com", presentingViewController: self)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

**Update for Swift 4.2**

For Swift 4.2, there are some changes in step 3, all other steps would remain same as above:

3) In `ViewDidLoad` write these lines

```
termsLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "By using this app you agree to the Privacy Policy & Terms & Conditions.")
guard let labelString = termsLabel.attributedText else {
            return
        }
        guard let privacyRange = labelString.string.range(of: "Privacy Policy") else {
            return
        }
        guard let termsConditionRange = labelString.string.range(of: "Terms & Conditions") else {
            return
        }

        let privacyNSRange: NSRange = labelString.string.nsRange(from: privacyRange)
        let termsNSRange: NSRange = labelString.string.nsRange(from: termsConditionRange)

        termsLabel.addLink(to: URL(string: "privacy"), with: privacyNSRange)
        termsLabel.addLink(to: URL(string: "terms"), with: termsNSRange)

        termsLabel.delegate = self
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: termsLabel.attributedText!)
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 12)!], range: termsNSRange)
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 12)!], range: privacyNSRange)
        attributedText.addAttributes([kCTForegroundColorAttributeName as NSAttributedString.Key : UIColor.orange], range: termsNSRange)
        attributedText.addAttributes([kCTForegroundColorAttributeName as NSAttributedString.Key : UIColor.green], range: privacyNSRange)
    attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: 0], range: termsNSRange)
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: 0], range: privacyNSRange)
```

Comment: do you have swift 4.0 solution?I am not getting multiple color in link.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 example for `TTTAttributedLabel`:

```
yourLabel.linkAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green,  
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSNumber(value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue)
]
yourLabel.activeLinkAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green,  
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSNumber(value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleDouble.rawValue)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3 using `TTTAttributedLabel`

```
let title: NSString = "Fork me on GitHub!"

var attirutedDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary:attributedLabel.linkAttributes)

attirutedDictionary[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.red
attirutedDictionary[NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName] =  NSNumber(value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue)

attributedLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: title as String)
attributedLabel.linkAttributes = attirutedDictionary as! [AnyHashable: Any]

let range = subtitleTitle.range(of: "me")
let url = URL(string: "http://github.com/mattt/")

attributedLabel.addLink(to: url, with: range)
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4.0 :

Short and simple

```
 let LinkAttributes = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: testLink.linkAttributes)
 LinkAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle] =  NSNumber(value: false)
 LinkAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor] = UIColor.black // Whatever your label color
 testLink.linkAttributes = LinkAttributes as NSDictionary as! [AnyHashable: Any]
```

Comment: UILabel does not have linkAttributes

Answer (score -2):

It's better to use **UITextView** with "Link" feature enabled. In this case you can do it with one line:

**Swift 4**:

```
// apply link attributes to label.attributedString, then
textView.tintColor = UIColor.red // any color you want
```

Full example:

```
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Here is my link")
    let range = NSRange(location: 7, length:4)
    attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "http://google.com", range: range)
    attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: range)
    attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineColor, value: UIColor.red, range: range)
    textView.tintColor = UIColor.red // any color you want
```

Or you can apply attributes to links only:

```
  textView.linkTextAttributes = [
      .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
      .underlineStyle: 1,
      .underlineColor: UIColor.red
   ]
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the link color is exactly the same. What are you using this on?

Comment: @Sirens Sorry. Actually, I used it for textView. I edited the answer above.