# How to add NSDictionary UIColor in iOS for TTTAttributedLabel LinkAttributes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicolor, tttattributedlabel

I have using a Xamarin binding for https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

And as per  - 
[Make link in UILabel.attributedText *not* blue and *not* underlined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381028/make-link-in-uilabel-attributedtext-not-blue-and-not-underlined)

```
self.label.linkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, 
                               NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)};
```

I would like to set my link attributes, I am just not sure of syntax -

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html

I have tried variations on these -

```
 label.LinkAttributes = new NSDictionary(
            new NSString("NSForegroundColorAttributeName"), UIColor.Red,
            new NSString("NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName"), new NSUnderlineStyle() == NSUnderlineStyle.Double);

 label.LinkAttributes = new NSDictionary(
            new NSString("NSForegroundColorAttributeName"), UIColor.Red,
            new NSString("NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName"), new NSNumber(2));
```

But not working.  Not sure how to pass in an UIColor as cannot see its Type available, it is doing "something" as its wiped my underline + blue colour with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line of code was taken from the github [README.md](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) from the project you linked.

```
(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName : (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
```

It looks like the library deals with `CGColor` and *not* `UIColor` (or `NSColor` which are OSX only). There's (too) many ways to represent colours and, sadly, most API only works with one. In this case you'll need to use:

```
UIColor.Red.CGColor
```

instead of:

```
UIColor.Red
```

in the dictionary you give to the `LinkAttributes` property of your label.

The key `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` (from your comment) must also match Apple's constant value, which can be different than the constant's name. In Xamarin.iOS this constant is exposed as:

```
CoreText.CTStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor
```

So it the library (re)uses the CoreText constants then this is the value to use.

Comment: Thank you @poupou, unfortunately its still is not working with .CGColor either, I am wondering if this alternative - label.linkAttributes = @{ (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor magentaColor],
(id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName : [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] }; call style mentioned in the SO answer above has something to do with, I am just not sure if I have the right key and putting in new NSString("Whatever"), UIColor.Red.CGColor); brings me the same result.

Comment: Updated answer based on your comment, i.e. it cannot be be any `NSString` key, it must be what the library looks for - which, from your comment, looks like its re-using CoreText constants.

Comment: Thank you sir, works like magic! -  label.LinkAttributes = new NSDictionary(
CoreText.CTStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor, UIColor.Red.CGColor);

Comment: A final point, is there a process for unearthing the CoreText Key Constant you posted or is it just experience?  I looked in the code and could not see a trail to follow nor by searching on google for the constant names and Xamarin etc ... thanks