# How to create clickable label Like Facebook in ios?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uilabel, clickablespan

I am developing a social app in which I need show post and sharing etc. 
I also need to show tag friend.

When post is show on list UI is also similar to Facebook post. Please check below screen shot. [image]

As you can see Clicking Post title is as attributed single line, Where I need to open User Profile when user click on his name that is **Person Name Abc** and want to open Page when user click on **Buzzfeed india**,

As we need to use a UILabel to display content like this I am not able to get click on particular word. I have already tried https://github.com/null09264/FRHyperLabel but when there is multiple line Then clicking on word is not perfect.

Comment: You may find your answer here: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541676/ios-uitextview-or-uilabel-with-clickable-links-to-actions**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) to make a particular part or words tappable in a UILabel.

For example

```
label.text = @"Fork me on GitHub!"; // Repository URL will be automatically detected and linked
NSRange range = [label.text rangeOfString:@"me"];
[label addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"meUrl"] withRange:range];
```

Here me becomes tappable and on tapping that word delegate method didSelectLinkWithURL gets called and you can check for that link inside that function

```
(void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"link %@", [url absoluteString]);
   if ([url absoluteString] == @"meUrl") {
   //implement your logic here
   }
    NSLog(@"whole label %@", label);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is work for me. but only problem is there is underline showing below clickable word. How I can remove that line.  https://prnt.sc/gl1csa

Comment: You can remove that by giving attributed text to label with the required color attribute

Comment: I have follow this answer to remove underline on clickable word  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381028/make-link-in-uilabel-attributedtext-not-blue-and-not-underlined

Comment: Great Thanks for sharing the info

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

Add Extension

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize

        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x:(labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,y:(labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);


        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x:locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,y:locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y);
        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
    }

}
```

> Then Add `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your UILable. Please make sure `UILabel.isUserInteractionEnabled` is true

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initialSetup()
    }

func initialSetup(){
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTap(_:)))
    lblTitle.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    lblTitle.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    lblTitle.numberOfLines = 0
    let personname = "Person Name Abc"
    let buzzIndia = "Buzzfeed india"
    let str = "\(personname) shared \(buzzIndia)'s video"
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:str)

    let range = (str as NSString).range(of: personname)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.black, range: range)
    if let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 14) {
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: range)
    }

    let rangeBuzz = (str as NSString).range(of: buzzIndia)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.black, range: rangeBuzz)
    if let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 14) {
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: rangeBuzz)
    }

    lblTitle.attributedText = attributedString

}

func didTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let text = (lblTitle.text)!
    let name = (text as NSString).range(of: "Person Name Abc")
    let buzzfeed = (text as NSString).range(of: "Buzzfeed india")

    if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: lblTitle, inRange: name) {
        //Repective "Person Name Abc" action
        print("Person Name Abc")
    }else if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: lblTitle, inRange: buzzfeed) {
        //Repective "Buzzfeed india" action
        print("Buzzfeed india")
    }else {
        print("other tapped")
    }
}
```

Reference: http://samwize.com/2016/03/04/how-to-create-multiple-tappable-links-in-a-uilabel/